# Strange quarks in neutron stars

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, neutron-stars

Recently I have read that the pressure within neutron stars can be so extreme that it can cause the deconfinement of quarks to form a kind of quark 'soup' and that these extreme conditions allow for the formation of strange quarks which may be the ideal form of matter and are very stable.So these quarks can turn other quarks into strange quarks leading to an uncontrolled chain reaction that can spread throughout the universe.

My confusion with this theory is that if this were the case,would'nt this have happened in the early universe itself when it had conditions more extreme than what we expect to see within neutron stars now?

Please excuse my hopelessly dumbed down way of asking this question.
Any insight will be helpful.